# Sampling the first non-zero column value per each row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
data = {"Column1":["0", "1", "0", "0", "1"], "Column2":["2","0","2", "0", "2"], "Column3":["3","0","3", "3", "3"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
  Column1 Column2 Column3
0       0       2       3
1       1       0       0
2       0       2       3
3       0       0       3
4       1       2       3
```

I want to get a dataframe that per each index of `df` has the first value that appears across the columns from left to right. The dataframe should look like this.

```
data1 = {"Column1":["2", "1", "2", "3", "1"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
print(df1)
  Column1
0       2
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       1
```

Could anyone tell me how to do it, please?

I am new to python so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much!

I thought this would work np.argmax(y, axis=1), but unfortunately it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Get first nonzero value from each row (with [`numpy.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) and [`numpy.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html)):

```
arr = df.astype(int).to_numpy()
s = pd.Series(np.take_along_axis(arr, np.argmax(arr > 0, axis=1)[:, None], axis=1).ravel())
print(s)
```

Or through `pd.DataFrame.apply` function:

```
s = df.astype(int).apply(lambda x: x[np.argmax(x > 0)], axis=1)
```

---

```
0    2
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `np.argmax()`

```
pd.DataFrame(np.argmax(df.to_numpy() != '0',axis=1)+1,columns = ['Column 1'])
```

Output:

```
   Column 1
0         2
1         1
2         2
3         3
4         1
```